# sort search results by custom fields using dropdown

Tags: custom-field, jquery, query, search, sort

On my search.php page, I have a "Sort By" dropdown that almost works exactly how I want it to --

```
<select class="dropdown-class" name="sort-posts" id="sortbox" onchange="document.location.href=location.href+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option disabled>Sort by</option>
<option value="&orderby=date&order=dsc">Newest</option>
<option value="&orderby=date&order=asc">Oldest</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    <?php if (( $_GET['orderby'] == 'date') && ( $_GET['order'] == 'dsc')) { ?>
        document.getElementById('sortbox').value='orderby=date&order=dsc';

    <?php } elseif (( $_GET['orderby'] == 'date') && ( $_GET['order'] == 'asc')) { ?>
        document.getElementById('sortbox').value='orderby=date&order=asc';

    <?php } else { ?>
        document.getElementById('sortbox').value='orderby=date&order=desc';

    <?php } ?>

</script>
```

When Im on the search results page, the sort dropdown will sort the current results according to date by grabbing the url and appending to it then reloading the page with the results ---

```
// Before
mydomain.com/?s=Search&property_city=new-york-city&beds=Any 

// After
mydomain.com/?s=Search&property_city=new-york-city&beds=Any&orderby=date&order=dsc
```

However, I am now trying to improve the code further by using it to sort based on numeric custom fields (high to low and low to high).

It seems all the info I can find on the subject have much more complicated ways of doing so. Is there anyway of doing this using the code I already started on?

**UPDATE**

I seem to be getting closer -

On my search.php page I have this before my loop ----

```
<select class="dropdown-class" name="sort-posts" id="sortbox" onchange="document.location.href=location.href+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option disabled>Sort by</option>
<option value="&orderby=date&order=dsc">Newest</option>
<option value="&orderby=date&order=asc">Oldest</option>
<option value="&orderby=property_price&order=asc">Most Expensive</option>
<option value="&orderby=property_price&order=dsc">Least Expensive</option>
<option value="&orderby=property_area&order=dsc">Largest</option>
<option value="&orderby=property_area&order=asc">Smallest</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    <?php if (( $_GET['orderby'] == 'date') && ( $_GET['order'] == 'dsc')) { ?>
        document.getElementById('sortbox').value='orderby=date&order=dsc';

    <?php } elseif (( $_GET['orderby'] == 'date') && ( $_GET['order'] == 'asc')) { ?>
        document.getElementById('sortbox').value='orderby=date&order=asc';

    <?php } elseif (( $_GET['orderby'] == 'property_price') && ( $_GET['order'] == 'asc')) { ?>
        document.getElementById('sortbox').value='orderby=property_price&order=asc';

        <?php } elseif (( $_GET['orderby'] == 'property_price') && ( $_GET['order'] == 'dsc')) { ?>
        document.getElementById('sortbox').value='orderby=property_price&order=dsc';

    <?php } elseif (( $_GET['orderby'] == 'property_area') && ( $_GET['order'] == 'asc')) { ?>
        document.getElementById('sortbox').value='orderby=property_area&order=asc';

        <?php } elseif (( $_GET['orderby'] == 'property_area') && ( $_GET['order'] == 'dsc')) { ?>
        document.getElementById('sortbox').value='orderby=property_area&order=dsc';


    <?php } else { ?>
        document.getElementById('sortbox').value='orderby=date&order=desc';

    <?php } ?>

</script>
```

where it says "orderby=xxx" I just use my names for my custom fields.

Comment: No I thought it was working but it's actually just sorting them randomly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it figured out using @Nicolai suggestion and also a answer from another question (which I seem to have lost the link to).

For starters, I had to make sure my numbers have no commas in it which I had already done by saving my post meta without it.

Then the code I found in another question, I used and placed into my **functions.php** file --

```
function wpse139657_orderby(){
    if( isset($_GET['orderby']) ){
        $order = $_GET['order'] or 'DESC';
        set_query_var('orderby', 'meta_value_num');
        //set_query_var('meta_type', 'numeric');
        set_query_var('meta_key', $_GET['orderby']);
        set_query_var('order', $order);
    }
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','wpse139657_orderby');
```

Then on my **search.php** page I used the following code for the select dropdown --

```
<select class="dropdown-class" name="sort-posts" id="sortbox" onchange="document.location.href=location.href+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option disabled>Sort by</option>
<option value="&orderby=date&order=dsc">Newest</option>
<option value="&orderby=date&order=asc">Oldest</option>
<option value="&orderby=property_price2&order=DESC">Most Expensive</option>
<option value="&orderby=property_price2&order=ASC">Least Expensive</option>
<option value="&orderby=area2&order=DESC">Largest</option>
<option value="&orderby=area2&order=ASC">Smallest</option>
</select>
```

This seems to do the trick and works with pagination, only issues I have right now is --

> 1. Ugly Urls
> 2. When the page is reloaded with the posts sorted, the dropdown select goes back to default ie "Newest" when it should still be on the
>      option the user chose.

Comment: You are looking for this one: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/139657/

Comment: It should be `set_query_var( 'orderby', $_GET[ 'orderby' ] );` and `set_query_var( 'meta_key', $_GET[ 'meta_key' ] )`, if you decide to set it up properly.

Comment: Problem 2 is because you are staring all values with "&". remove it.

Answer (score 1):

`orderby` should be e.g. `meta_value` or `meta_value_num` – various specific `meta_type`'s are available – to order by meta data. Additionally a `meta_key` has to be set and present in the query. To be exact and     to avoid misunderstandings, `meta_key` has to be the `keyname` of the field you're sorting by. Take a closer look at the [Order & Orderby Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) and [Custum Fields Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) section of the `WP_Query` documentation for more information.

Comment: Like this? `<option value="&orderby=meta_value_num&meta_type=numeric&meta_key=property_price&order=asc">Most Expensive</option>`

Comment: @RichJ No, `meta_type` is an aspect of `meta_value_*`, not a parameter. So while you could use `meta_value_numeric`, there already exists the predating `meta_value_num`. There are other types, like `CHAR`, `DATE`, `TIME` and so forth.  All this is part of the documentaion, I would recommend to read it.

Comment: I have, and I've tried applying it to my situation but with no luck.

Comment: @RichJ Setting `orderby` to `meta_value_num` and `meta_key` to a numeric field should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Form will automaticly add your select value to url when you submit form. There is no need to create such a value `&orderby=date&order=dsc`. If you want to pass multiple information in single select value you can use simpler value and if statement. For newest option I would use `newest` as value and add make such a if statement.

```
// Url /?s=test&order=newest

$orderby = '';
$order = '';

// Get filtered $_GET['order'] parameter
$value = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'order', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

if( $value === 'newest' ) {
    $orderby = 'date';
    $order = 'desc';
}

// Modify query using $orderby and $order parameters
```

Using JavaScript to select option for me is also bad idea. You should check current `order` parameter and add selected attribute to your option.

```
// Url /?s=test&order=newest

// Get filtered $_GET['order'] parameter
$value = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'order', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
$selected = ($value === 'newest') ? 'selected': '' ;
?>

<select name="order">
    <option value="newest" <?php echo esc_attr( $selected ); ?>></option>
</select>
```

I think you should not bother making nice url. For a small number of parameters it might be tempting to make nice url but when your app is getting bigger adding  additional rewrite case and logic to it is purposeless. If you have to convince your boss or client to give up on nice urls show them Amazon on search page. I'm considering them as specialist and they do not use nice urls during search.

Code below is fully working example how to sort post by `date`, `price` and `size`. Execute `wpse_288655_display_form` function in place where you want to display the sorting form.

```
/**
 * Display sort form
 */
function wpse_288655_display_form() {

    /**
     * Get all params from url which are not part of our sort form
     * and display it in form as hidden inputs.
     */
    $search_param = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 's', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );

    /**
     * Current order value to select proper field
     */
    $value = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'order', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
    ?>

    <form method="get">
        <?php wpse_288655_display_select('order', 'Sort by:', wpse_288655_get_order_by_options(), $value ); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * Display all params from url which do not apply to our sort form
             */
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="s" value="<?php esc_attr_e( $search_param ); ?>">

        <button type="submit"><?php esc_html_e('Sort'); ?></button>
    </form>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Get sort options
 */
function wpse_288655_get_order_by_options(){

    return array(
        '' => '',
        'newest' => __('Newest'),
        'oldest' => __('Oldest'),
        'most_expensive' => __('Most Expensive'),
        'least_expensive' => __('Least Expensive'),
        'largest' => __('Largest'),
        'smallest' => __('Smallest'),
    );
}

/**
 * Display select field
 */
function wpse_288655_display_select( $name, $label, $options, $value = '' ) {
    ?>
    <label><?php esc_html_e( $label ) ?></label>
    <select name="<?php esc_attr_e( $name ) ?>">
        <?php wpse_288655_display_options( $options, $value ); ?>
    </select>
    <?php
}

/**
 * Display select options
 */
function wpse_288655_display_options( $options, $value ) {

    foreach( $options as $option_value => $option_label ):
        $selected = ( $option_value === $value ) ? ' selected' : '';
        ?>
        <option value="<?php esc_attr_e( $option_value ) ?>"<?php esc_attr_e( $selected ) ?>><?php esc_html_e( $option_label ) ?></option>
        <?php

    endforeach;
}

/**
 * Sort posts using pre_get_posts filter
 */
function wpse_288655_order_posts( $query ) {

    /**
     * Execute query only when we are on search page and this is main query
     */
    if ( $query->is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {

        $value = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'order', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING );
        $order_by_options = wpse_288655_get_order_by_options();

        if( isset( $order_by_options[ $value ] ) && !empty( $value ) ) {

            switch( $value ) {
                case 'newest':

                    $query->set( 'order', 'desc' );
                    $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );

                    break;

                case 'oldest':

                    $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
                    $query->set( 'orderby', 'date' );

                    break;
                case 'most_expensive':

                    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'price' ); // Your custom meta_key

                    $query->set( 'order', 'desc' );
                    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );

                    break;
                case 'least_expensive':

                    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'price' ); // Your custom meta_key

                    $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
                    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );

                    break;
                case 'largest':

                    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'size' ); // Your custom meta_key

                    $query->set( 'order', 'desc' );
                    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );

                    break;
                case 'smallest':

                    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'size' ); // Your custom meta_key

                    $query->set( 'order', 'asc' );
                    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'wpse_288655_order_posts');
```

Comment: it has to be dynamic though, without a submit button

Comment: Just trigger submit event on form when select change using JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

For the below answers look very uncertain - for example you can not just hook `pre_get_posts` because it affects every query on the website, even in WordPress admin area.

My first recommendation for you is to refuse of using JavaScript, I'd like to make your dropdown to look like this:

```
<form action="" method="GET"><select name="sortposts">
    <option disabled>Sort by</option>
    <option value="date-DESC">Newest</option>
    <option value="date-ASC">Oldest</option>
    <option value="property_price-ASC">Most Expensive</option>
    <option value="property_price-DESC">Least Expensive</option>
.....
```

Great, now in the same `search.php` file you can do this:

```
<?php
    global $wp_query;

    // let's create new array with args
    if( !empty( $_GET['sortposts'] ) ) {
        // I recommend to explode it because we're take 2 param values from one $_GET variable
        $sort_args = explode( "-", $_GET['sortposts'] );
        // $sort_args[0] is what we sort
        // $sort_args[1] is how we sort - Ascending or Descending
        $new_args['order'] = $sort_args[1];
        if( $sort_args[0] == 'date' ) {
            // date is a default WP_Query value, so we do nothing
            $new_args['orderby'] == 'date';
        } elseif( $sort_args[0] == 'property_price' ) {
            $new_args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
            $new_args['meta_key'] = 'THIS IS A PROPERTY PRICE META KEY';
        }
    }

    $args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, $new_args );
    query_posts( $args );
```

Something like that. But you can use pre_get_posts of course if you want. Just add conditions there, so the filter won't fire on non-relevant pages.

If you would like to implement the filtering with AJAX, you can look at this tutorial as well https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/ajax-load-more-with-filters.html